# RHEL 6.x kick start

Tags: linux, unix, redhat, rhel

I am trying do a kickstart using ftp and http. I tried to look online material but i couldn't find any that is very descriptive. I would really appreciate if anyone know of it or help me with the link for that content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this help - FTP and HTTP should both work -

https://access.redhat.com/site/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Installation_Guide/sn-automating-installation.html

Answer (score 0):

LinuxCBT EL-3 Edition Go for this. It explains everything in linux in detail. I learned the basics of linux with Linux CBT.

http://www.linuxcbt.com/products_linuxcbt.php